# How to change values in data depending on group median

Tags: r, dplyr

A simple example to reproduce

```r
d1 = structure(list(et = c("s", "s"), gg = c("d", "d"), hj = c("f", 
    "f"), ggh = c("h", "h"), wer = c(23L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))
```

where `et`, `gg`, `hj` and `ggh` are categorical variables and `wer` is a metric variable. So, for this category

```
    et  gg  hj  ggh
    s   d   f   h
```

the median (by `wer`) is `34`.

There is a second dataset

```r
d2 <- structure(list(et = "s", gg = "d", hj = "f", ggh = "h", wer = 3L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L))
```

for this category

```r
    et  gg  hj  ggh
    s   d   f   h
```

`wer` equals `3`

How to do that if in the dataset `d2` the value `wer` for the same categories with d1,  less or greater than the median from d1 for this category on 1, then in d2 put the value of the median in this category.
So in this simple example desired output in `d2` will be

```r
    et  gg  hj  ggh wer
    s   d   f   h   34
```

because 3 from the d2 dataset is less than 34 (the median for this category in d1) by 31.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "less or greater than the median from d1" so, in every case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the median of `d1` and then do a `right_join` on `d2`:

```r
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  group_by(across(-wer)) %>% 
  summarise(wer = median(wer), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  right_join(d2, by = c("et", "gg", "hj", "ggh"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(wer = ifelse(wer >= wer.y, wer, wer.y), .keep = "unused")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  et    gg    hj    ggh     wer
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 s     d     f     h        34
```